# Search scrolling div menu with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a scrolling menu in jquery that scrolls vertically on mouseover: (part of it is hidden until scrolled into view)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Scroll the menu on mouse move above the #sidebar layer
    $('#sidebar').mousemove(function(e) {

        //Sidebar Offset, Top value
        var s_top = parseInt($('#sidebar').offset().top);

        //Sidebar Offset, Bottom value
        var s_bottom = parseInt($('#sidebar').height() + s_top);

        //Roughly calculate the height of the menu by multiply height of a single LI with the total of LIs
        var mheight = parseInt($('#menu li').height() * $('#menu li').length);


        //Calculate the top value
        //This equation is not the perfect, but it 's very close    
        var top_value = Math.round(((s_top - e.pageY) / 100) * mheight / 2);

        //Animate the #menu by chaging the top value
        $('#menu').animate({
            top: top_value
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 5000
        });
    });
});​
</script>
```

and then I am using a search and highlight jquery script to search for a name in the scrolling menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#text-search').bind('keyup change', function(ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();)

    // remove any old highlighted terms
    $('#sidebar').removeHighlight();

    // disable highlighting if empty
    if (searchTerm) {
        // highlight the new term
        $('#sidebar').highlight(searchTerm);
    }
    });
});​
</script>
```

However my issue is:  when i type in the search term, it will only highlight the menu items that are visible.  How do I get jquery to automatically scroll to the searched term within the div?

Answer (score 1):

something along the lines of:

```
var searchTermTop,
    searchTermBottom;

searchTermTop = searchTerm.offsetParent().top;
searchTermBottom = searchTerm.offsetParent().bottom;

if(searchTermTop < 0){
    //set the menu scroll to it's current scroll + the searchTermTop
}
if(searchTermBottom > mheight){
    //set the menu scroll to it's current scroll + the searchTermBottom
}
```

Something along those lines. If you need more specifics let me know. Need to run out of the office now or I'd fill in the details a bit.

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me -can you be more specific on where I would place it in the code?  Thanks!

Comment: I'll try and work up a working demo for you. Can you give me the html you are working with? Would save me some time over reverse engineering from your js.

Comment: Sure - do you have an email I can send it to, to make it easier?

Comment: lol why the heck not. I need something to do besides real work this weekend. :P   jchagan80 at hotmail dot com. I'm going to be so annoyed if someone else shows up with an answer before I can finish. ;)

Comment: A bit, not done yet. I ended up having to rewrite a fair bit of what you have to make it work in my head, and possibly play nice with scrolling to the target. Only had a few hours on sunday to mess with it though. Maybe more tonight. :/

Comment: Hi--any progress?  I really need to have this done in the next couple of days.  If you don't have time--no worries.  Thanks!